# How to assign a static ID to a display in Linux?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xorg

A bit of context first, I've used Yakuake for years now, it's not perfect, it has its bugs here and there but generally works great for me.

I have recently moved to using a multiple monitors setup (2 + laptop screen) and even though Yakuake has a setting to select in which screen you want it to display, listing them by an incremental id (Screen 1, Screen 2, etc.). However I've noticed this doesn't work with multiple monitors.

[image: yakuake configuration popup screen]

Every time I restart my laptop or bring it back from sleep state, it seems to me the screen/display IDs change and Yakuake starts popping up on a different screen every time.

Is it possible to set static IDs to displays so I can configure Yakuake to display on that ID and have it be consistent?

A bit more context, I'm using Kubuntu 22.04 with Xorg in a Thinkpad with a embedded/built-in AMD GPU. Hopefully that helps.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it, but a solution to the problem is claimed in the post
[Yakuake and other app windows forget what screen/position to start in](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/nnh7jl/fix_yakuake_and_other_app_windows_forget_what/):

> At least as of Kubuntu 21.04, KDE Plasma 5.21.90 what you want to fix
> this is:
>
> - Open System Settings > Window Management > Window Rules
> - Click Add New
> - Set "Window Class (application)" to "Substring Match" and enter text value as the window title you are trying to control
>
>   - Alternatively you can open the app and use the "Detect Window Properties" to capture the desired matcher
> - Set Match whole window class to "Yes"
> - Set Window types to "All selected"
>
>   - Can be "Normal Window" for a regular app but, it's fine to leave them all checked
> - Click Add Property, choose "Screen"
> - Set combo selection to "Force" and number selection to the screen you want the app to open on
>
>   - In my case, 0 made it to open on the center screen
> - Click Apply
> - Close app, reopen, and check if it opens on the desired screen
>
>   - You may have to experiment to get it to stick to the right screen
>
> The process is basically the same for any other properties you want to
> set like size and position. This is what it looked like for my Yakuake
> settings so you know if you're on the right track.
>
> [image]